# HTML and CSS format

Tags: html

[image: comment]

I want to implement a website with the above format for inputs.

Can anyone give some ideas which tags are supposed to be used?

And the brief idea how I should implement it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: View the source code of the site that you are trying to emulate. Better still, learn to use your browser's developer tools to inspect the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use placeholder for modern browsers:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Question 1: What do you want?" />
```

For older browsers you need a Javascript that will replace the value of the element with a placeholder. Which can be found here: http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/

Answer (score 0):

For a simple format to the question above you can use the following code

```
<p>Write a comment...</p>

<input type="text" placeholder="Question 1: What is your comment reguarding the post's grammer and typos?" /><br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Question 2: ..." />
```

The main tag you should use is the input with type `text`.

The placeholder is an attribute of the input tag which would display any text you like inside of the input box.